# How to Subscribe to two different Publishers

Tags: java

I have a User object which needs to respond to two different Publisher changes:

```
public class User implements Subscriber<Language>, Subscriber<TimeZone>
{ 
    public User()
    {
        super();

        Languages.getInstance().subscribe( this );
        TimeZones.getInstance().subscribe( this );
    }
}

@Override
public void onNext( Language language )
{
}

@Override
public void onNext( TimeZone timezone)
{
}
```

However I am getting an error: `The interface Subscriber cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Flow.Subscriber<TimeZone> and Flow.Subscriber<Language>`.

It was possible to `Observe` two different events, but that has been deprecated. How do I do this with the new methodology? Do I have to create a new object which contains both `Language` and `TimeZone` and then create that, and then test for which one is not null for processing?

Comment: Can you subscribe to the observables using lambda expressions? Something like `subscribe(lang -> { ... });`?

Comment: Like the message says: you can't subscribe to two different things at once.  The cleanest solution is a separate class for each subscription, and presumably a third class to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll have to go with:

```
 public class SubscribeContainer
 {
    private Object ivObject;

    public SubscribeContainer( Object object )
    {
        ivObject = object;
    }

    public Object getObject()
    {
        return ivObject;
    }
}
```

and then

```
    @Override
    public void onNext( SubscribeContainer container )
    {
       Object object = container.getObject();

        if (object instanceof TimeZone)
        {
         TimeZone newZone = (TimeZone) object;

         // and so on
        } 
    }
```